# Can we run Asterisk on our MAXIMISER 4140 Call Server with Slicecomm PCS100s?

Tags: asterisk

We currently have a MAXIMISER 4140 Call Server, a MAXIMISER 4315 Phone system and about 20 Slicecomm PCS100 (voip phones)

Can we somehow run Asterisk using this hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks (from the technical information available on their site) to be an asterisk based appliance already (just looking at the features and how the system is put together)

so I guess the quick answer would be no, you probably can't download asterisk and install it on the appliance, but you can download it and install it on a normal server and probably make use of the phones.

A quick way to test would be grab a [trixbox iso](http://www.trixbox.org/downloads), which will give you an easy to install asterisk server to play with. you can then see if the phones can be registered as regular SIP phones and go from there...

Answer (score 2):

No. The Splicecom is not an Asterisk system. Although Linux based it is very different, being the only British designed and built PABX available today.